# How to set value of hidden field in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, hidden-field

I need to set the value  12, which is defined as   `Public PageSize As Integer = 12` in aspx page, to the  hidden field in vb.net.I defined hidden field as :

```
<asp:HiddenField    id="ivar" runat="server" Value="<%= PageSize  %>"/>.
```

After running the  code and took view source it is just   `<input type="hidden" name="ivar" id="ivar" value="&lt;%= PageSize  %>" />`.Not got as `<input type="hidden" name="ivar" id="ivar" value="12" />`

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes instead of double:

```
value='<%= PageSize  %>"/>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:HiddenField id="ivar" runat="server" Value="<%#Eval("PageSize")%>"/>
```

plz try this